# Regex query for email validation to also include .ac.uk in php

Tags: php, validation

I have searched and searched online and on Stack Overflow for some guidance, but nothing quite fits in with the code I have. I am using PHP to carry out some validation on my users signup form seen as below and I want to also check that the user signing up has an email that ends in `.ac.uk`:

```
  // We check for any empty inputs. 
  if (empty($firstName) || empty($lastName) || empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($passwordRepeat)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=emptyfields&username=".$username."&email=".$email);
    exit();
  }
  // We check for an invalid username AND invalid e-mail.
  else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidunamemail");
    exit();
  }
  // Check for an invalid username. In this case ONLY letters and numbers allowed.
  else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidcharacters");
    exit();
  }

  // Check for minimum amount of characters in username.
  else if (strlen($username) <7 ) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidlengthuname");
    exit();
  }

  // Check for an invalid e-mail. <-- Here is where I also want to add the check of .ac.uk at the end of the email
  else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidemail");
    exit();
  }
  // Check if the repeated password is NOT the same.
  else if ($password !== $passwordRepeat) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=passwordcheck&uname");
    exit();
  }
  else {
// Login
```

Comment: strpos() function performed on email field should resolve the problem.
Just remember to use it with strict comparison to false because it returns index, not boolean so if you get index of 0, it will be treated as false inside 'if' statement (when no strict comparison).

Comment: Hello @GrzegorzLasak would this be something along the sort of lines you have suggested: `else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && (strpos($email, "ac.uk") == false)) { `

Comment: If you don't want to allow users to use email NOT containing 'ac.uk' then yes, except use strict comparison '===' (3x '=') because 0 will be treated as FALSE when only 2x '=' used :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `preg_match` to check, Although this may skip the second condition if condition one works. This is weird but if added separately it works

```
  // Check for an invalid e-mail. <-- Here is where I also want to add the check of .ac.uk at the end of the email
  if ( !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)  &&  preg_match('/ac.uk$/', $email) ) {

      header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidemail");
      exit();
  }
```

This one will work

```
  // Check for an invalid e-mail. <-- Here is where I also want to add the check of .ac.uk at the end of the email
  if ( !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

      header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidemail");
      exit();
  } 
  if (!preg_match('/ac.uk$/', $email)) { 

      header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidemail");
      exit();

  }
```

Comment: Hello, I'm afraid it's still allowing users to sign up on my form even without the .ac.uk at the end of the email, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: That is weird. i have tried to put the condition separately and it works. still looking into it.

Comment: Hi Omari, the 2nd answer you posted works great, thank you so much. Weird that it doesn't work within the same `if` statement. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expression to Email Regex matching specific domain

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?(yourdomain)\.ac.uk$
```

[Demo](https://www.regextester.com/94044)

Here are [More examples](https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

**UPDATE** : on your comment check for extention first if its an acceptable domain then validate.

```
$email = 'test@domain.ac.uk';
$extention = pathinfo($email, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if($extension == ".ac.uk"){
   //Do your validation here 
   filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
}else{
   //Invalid extention Reject email
}
```

Comment: Hi, so I'm not actually stating the regex laid out in long form due to php having the `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`, so just not sure how I would add on the end part of `.ac.uk`